# React Native Blank White Screen in Android

Tags: android, ubuntu, reactjs, react-native

I was following this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html, but when i build the project using this command: `react-native run-android`, i got this message

> Starting JS server... Running
>   /home/nakama/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 915fdc90 reverse
>   tcp:8081 tcp:8081 adb server version (32) doesn't match this client
>   (36); killing...
>   * daemon started successfully * Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug... :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0350Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:validateDebugSigning :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:installDebug Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Mi 4i - 5.0.2'
>   Installed on 1 device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 20.971 secs
>
> This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon:
>   http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Starting the
>   app (/home/nakama/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n
>   com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity... adb server version (32) doesn't
>   match this client (36); killing...
>   * daemon started successfully * Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }

and the result is my apps always shows blank screen. I did not change any single javascript code on those project, what is the root caused which makes my apps always give me a blank screen ?

Comment: All i need just to activate DEVELOPER MODE on the mobile device (emulator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set your ip address in developer menu of react native. Follow this link
[Running on android device.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html) to run on android device.

Answer (score 0):

When you using this command: 'react-native run-android'. You should use press 'R' twice times or Ctrl + M (open option menu and choose reload) to reload screen and see result. I recommend use Genymotion for android emulator.

Cheer! =))

Comment: i'm using my own device mi4i to debug, and when i run command Ctrl + M ?, after all process 'react-native run-android' command had done ? or while process 'react-native run-android' running ?

Comment: is it not recomended to use my own device rather than using emulator like genymotion ?

Comment: @JaisAnasrullohJa'fari on real devices you can shake devices to show option menu and make reload screen. =))